# Copy the code from JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

Sorry for the stupid question...I found other similar question but I couldn't figure it out.

I don't understan why it doesn't work. I copy the code from http://jsfiddle.net/sB49B/21/

I think the problem should be the onload but i'm not sure because what I tried didn't work.
I tride to include the code in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  code javascript
)};
```

and in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  code javascript
)};
```

Do you have any Idea??! This is the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Here the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>jsfiddle.net/sB49B/18/</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var oDebug = $('p#debug');
      var oItemsContainer = $('ul#items');
      $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var iScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var iScrollPerItem = 200;
        var aItems = oItemsContainer.children('li.item');
        var iCurrentIndex = Math.floor(iScrollTop / iScrollPerItem);
        var fOpacity= (iScrollTop % iScrollPerItem) / iScrollPerItem ;
        aItems.filter(':lt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').show();
        aItems.filter(':gt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').hide();
        aItems.eq(iCurrentIndex).show().css('opacity', fOpacity);
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { height:3000px; }
      ul#items { width:200px; height:200px; position:fixed; top:10px; left:10px; }
      ul#items li.item {background-color:#dddddd; display:block; height:100%; left:0; opacity:0; position:absolute; right:0; width:100%;}
      p#debug {position:fixed; right:10px; text-align:right; top:10px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="debug">n/a</p>
    <ul id="items">
      <li class="item item01">1</li>
      <li class="item item02">2</li>
      <li class="item item03">3</li>
      <li class="item item04">4</li>
      <li class="item item05">5</li>
      <li class="item item06">6</li>
      <li class="item item07">7</li>
      <li class="item item08">8</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `)}` -> `})` fix your typos.

Comment: sorry I had to be melted

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is coming because you didn't closed brackets properly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  code javascript
)};
```

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      code javascript
    });
```

Notice the difference between last line

Answer (score 0):

Let's read the error... Unexpected token )... Well, maybe a misplaced ) character.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oDebug = $('p#debug');
    var oItemsContainer = $('ul#items');
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var iScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var iScrollPerItem = 200;
        var aItems = oItemsContainer.children('li.item');
        var iCurrentIndex = Math.floor(iScrollTop / iScrollPerItem);
        var fOpacity= (iScrollTop % iScrollPerItem) / iScrollPerItem ;
        aItems.filter(':lt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').show();
        aItems.filter(':gt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').hide();
        aItems.eq(iCurrentIndex).show().css('opacity', fOpacity);
    });
});
```

Your last line `)};` is wrong. It should be `});`, the first to close is `}` of the `function() {` and then the `)` from `.ready(`.

Comment: sorry I had to be melted

Comment: @user2295617 erm... what??

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  var oDebug = $('p#debug');
  var oItemsContainer = $('ul#items');
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var iScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var iScrollPerItem = 200;
    var aItems = oItemsContainer.children('li.item');
    var iCurrentIndex = Math.floor(iScrollTop / iScrollPerItem);
    var fOpacity= (iScrollTop % iScrollPerItem) / iScrollPerItem ;
    aItems.filter(':lt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').show();
    aItems.filter(':gt(' + iCurrentIndex  + ')').hide();
    aItems.eq(iCurrentIndex).show().css('opacity', fOpacity);
  });
 }
</script>
```

and check the console looking for "ready!"
if you see it, the problem is with the logic